# Can someone explain this linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm having a tough time understanding how this linear transformation works...
[image]

Comment: The transformation is multiplication to the permutation matrix. It simply switches the places of the elements of the 2x1 vectors. Try multiplying each column vector the 2x2 matrix and see.

Comment: For example, the 2x2 is A and the vectors that are 2x1 are x, and y. L(x) = Ax and L(y) = Ay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the left figure, the points $\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 2\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$ are pictured (using coordinates $\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y\end{bmatrix}$). Multiplying $\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$, and multiplying $\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$, so these are the two points pictured in the right figure.

The linear transformation being pictured is $T\left(\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}\right) = \begin{bmatrix} y \\ x \end{bmatrix}$, which corresponds to left-multiplication by the given matrix, i.e.
\begin{equation}T\left(\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}\right) = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y\end{bmatrix}.\end{equation}

Comment: It's worth remarking too that this transformation has precisely the effect of reflecting a vector across the line $x = y$.

Comment: ohh i see. i got my final product as a 2x2 matrix and was confused. then i looked online and apparently matrix multiplication is not commutative.

Answer (score 2):

Well, geometrically, this linear transformation acts as follows:

[image]

Therefore, the linear transformation is in fact a composition of a reflection in the horizontal axis and a rotation along the negative vertical axis.